# Convert adjacency matrix to graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is there any online service that can provide possible graphs (the simplest one) when I give a sequence of integers (node degrees) as input (or reject the input) -based on Erdős-Gallai formula?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you elaborate which role the Erdős-Gallai formula should play there? An adjacency matrix actually already "IS" (or "represents") a graph (and I assume that you'd like to see it in form of a node-link-diagram, which is just one visual representation of a graph)

Comment: If you have a matrix and you want to check if its a valid adjacency matrix, all you need to do is check that its entries are in {0,1}, the diagonal is zero and the matrix is symmetric. You can write a quick script to convert the adjacency matrix to an adjacency list and plot it with graphviz's neato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you'r after a graph that realizes a *degree sequence* (if possible), since this is what the [Erdős–Gallai Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) is about.  These graphs can be constructed by the Havel-Hakimi algorithm (a description is on [the Wikipedia page for degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29)).

It's straightforward:  Each vertex is labeled by its remaining degree (starting off with the specified degree sequence).  In each iteration, we take a vertex $v$ of maximum degree $d$, and connect it to $d$ vertices that have the maximum remaining degree.  This drops the remaining degree of $v$ to $0$ and each of its new neighbors' remaining degrees by $1$.

Moreover, the algorithm fails if and only if the degree sequence is not realizable.